# Former organisational email address taken over after resignation [UK]

Tags: united-kingdom

I have recently resigned (under circumstances of conflict) from a voluntary director role on the board of an organisation.  This organisation used G-Suite to manage documents and a director email list.

As is standard, upon my resignation, my account was locked and should have been archived.

However, I've just received a security alert from Google, indicating that my password has been reset by the admin (another director) and that someone has now logged in to the account.

I only used the account for professional purposes, so there is nothing untoward for them to find.  However, they are now able to receive new email as me, and impersonate me if they wish.

Recovering the account through Google is not an option, as Google directs me to "Contact your domain admin for help" if I use the "forgot password" button.

Is this covered in any way by any data protection act or digital privacy act, or is this something that an organisation who hosts email is allowed to do?

Comment: If it's an account purely for the organisation's business then presumably the organisation has the right to control who uses it. If you used it just in your professional capacity, what personal or private information are you concerned about them accessing or processing? And a word of caution - *if* you are no longer authorised to use that account there's a *possibility* of committing an offence under the [Computer Misuse Act](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1990/18/section/1?timeline=false) if you try to log in to it.

Answer (score 2):

### It is, and always was, their account

Email accounts belong to the account owner, not the individual who uses the account.

If they were to use the account to impersonate you, that might be illegal. However, if they use it for archiving purposes, to access the contract lists within it and to advise that you are no longer with the organisation, that’s fine.

Comment: This may be correct, but may oversimplify the law.  At least under GDPR, some employee data (though I'm not sure to what degree that includes email) is considered "personal data" and may have some restrictions on how some employee data is processed.  I'm not sure how the UK's Data Protection Act handles it.